# Can I use the Analog pins on Arduino micro as digital pins?

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, analog, pins

Can I use the Analog pins on Arduino Micro as digital pins? if Yes are there any Analog pins I cant use as digital pins on the Arduino micro?

Comment: What does Arduino Micro manual says about how to use them?

Comment: I think closing the answer as duplicated is not valid. First, because the Arduino Micro is not a classical arduino (ie based on an Atmega328p), and therefore generic answers about arduinos (which one can assume to be the classical ones, as there are so many now) may not apply. Whats more, the liked answer is even WRONG for some classical arduinos. For example, on Arduino Nano, analog pins A6 and A7 can't be used as digital outputs (https://forum.arduino.cc/t/can-nano-rx-a6-a7-be-used-as-digital-outputs/545807)

Comment: The Arduino Micro is a "special" arduino (ie not a classical one), which is based on the ATmega32U4. If you look at the arduino shop (https://store.arduino.cc/products/arduino-micro), you have a pinout diagram, showing for each analog pin (A0 to A12) also the corresponding digital pin number (for exemple A7=D6). So it should be possible to use any analog pin as digital pin (nb : to be completletly sure, it would require either reading the datasheet of ATmega32U4 + the schematics of the Arduino Micro, or if you already have it, then just test it)